# How to encode md5 sum to base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, md5, cryptojs

I have a login web form, user writes his password and I must encrypt it on MD5 and the sum to base 64. I'm doing like this with CryptoJS:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(cred.password); // password is `password`
cred.password = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==  --  IT IS OK!
```

This works fine. Then I must convert the following string to MD5 and Base64 too:

```
var digest = "john.doe,"+hash.toString()+",QCiTzbXCAYA3AvDgYN3MuBwY/1i89q6TfW7aVS1Av1c=";
```

again I do:

```
var hash1 = CryptoJS.MD5(digest);
digestResult = hash1.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

It returns `i4a9M2b6l+yBZLHc3bXWMA==` but the expected by the server for this conbination is `6R1HZqYJFfRQUA0L/hqCEA==`

I guess Crypto is not working for a base64/md5 inside the string to convert?

I dont get why it returns bad

Comment: "password and I must encrypt it on MD5", please use something like bcrypt and not MD5.

Comment: Sorry, but I must use MD5, I cannot use something else

Comment: The server side method is expecting in MD5, and I cannot change the method

Comment: Well don't expect any replies, MD5 should never be used for password hashing.

Comment: I know, sadly I didn't decide this

Comment: Anyway I guess I must not be a so hard question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `CryptoJS.MD5(cred.password)` returns a `typedArray`, not a string. It has a `toString` function which returns the common hexadecimal representation. All of that won't fit very well together. You'll need to probe the client/server strings to see what one sends and the other accepts but you should use the hexadecimal string representation all the way up to the final base64 encoding, mixing them is not very healthy.
**EDIT** after some comments given by the OP

```
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(cred.password); // password is `password`
// "hash" contains a typed array, needs to be base64
hash = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // X01jw2Jap2XWHYMn3riCz5k=
var digest = "john.doe,"+hash+",QCiTzbXCAYA3AvDgYN3MuBwY/1i89q6TfW7aVS1Av1c=";
digest = CryptoJS.MD5(digest);
digest = digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // jH+dH56sKswaDDfeCzDY0A==
// send "digest" to server
```

Cannot go further without knowledge of server-side code.

Comment: I have updated the `toString()`, how ever, I still get different value.
The digest and the cred.password I must post to the a REST service (With another values), and it checks the digest.. but it's not creating the same base64 String at the end

Comment: The we need more: an example input for `cred.password`, let's take the string "password". The MD5sum (tested with `md5sum` from the coreutils) for that string is `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`. Is your output the same for that exact string? What string does the server expect for that exact password? What do you do with teh base64 encoded string you have put in `cred.password`?

Comment: Yes, this is the string.
According to backend programmers, this string
`john.doe,5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99,QCiTzbXCAYA3AvDgYN3MuBwY/1i89q6TfW7aVS1Av1c=` to MD5 and then to Base64 should return `6R1HZqYJFfRQUA0L/hqCEA==`

Comment: What is the intermediate MD5sum of "john.doe,5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99,QCiTzbXCAYA3AvDgYN3MuBwY/1i89q6TfW7aV‌​S1Av1c=" supposed to be? I got `a296523291d1d7af4543c67cba8574ae` which translates to `OWExOGYyM2ZhM2JiODNlYmIyYmI5MWQ4OTM4NjE3MTggIC0K` in base64

Comment: According to Crypto the MD5 returns `1c55c9f294f726a11c408f77b527e604` :/

Comment: If I do "raw" bytes I get `X01jw2Jap2XWHYMn3riCz5k=` for the password and `jH+dH56sKswaDDfeCzDY0A==` for the rest. The length alone gives the a hint: they want the base64 of the *raw bytes*, the base64 CryptoJs delivers. You've put it into 'cred.password' which you never used. Put that in the long string and use the CryptJS base64 on that long string,too, before you send it to the server..

Comment: For me hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) still returns a Hex string.  I had to do btoa(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)) to get the Base64 encoded version of the MD5 value.